# Working on Android OpenGL lesson can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to do this lesson
http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/environment.html
Every time I start the app it just crashes and eclipse doesn't tell me what wrong.
Here's my code

```
package com.example.opengl;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;

public class MyGL20Renderer implements MyGLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Redraw Background Color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    }



}
```

Next class

```
package com.example.opengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceVIew
        setRenderer(new MyGL20Renderer());
        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);
    }

}
```

Finally manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.opengl"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.opengl.MyGLSurfaceView" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I've been trying to google to solve this problem, but my google kung fu is too weak.

Comment: To find out the reason for the crash, check the "logcat". I'm not familiar with Eclipse, so I don't know exactly where to find this. I'm certain google will have details for you, though.

Comment: I found the logcat. In eclispe there're three button up in the top right. Debug,Java, and DDMS. If you hit debug it switch you to a debug view. But now I cant get it to crash again, and I didn't make any change to code since last night. Oh well. On a side note is there anyway to make this debug like C++ and jump to the line it's crashing on?

Comment: Yes. Check out  http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html and http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html.

Answer (score 2):

What about your main activity? Did you forget this?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
    // as the ContentView for this Activity.;
    mGLView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mGLView);

    }
}
```

I'm also stuck with this example, although my program starts just fine afterwards it only shows a black screen and not what is declared in:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
}
```

EDIT: Found my error. I had the wrong import in MyGL20Renderer which created another onSurfaceChanged method.